# What is the difference between upsampling and bi-linear upsampling in a CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to understand [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00915) and am unsure of what bi-linear upsampling is. Can anyone explain this at a high-level?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the context of image processing, upsampling is a technique for increasing the size of an image.

For example, say you have an image with a height and width of $64$ pixels each (totaling $64 \times 64 = 4096$ pixels). You want to resize this image to a height and width of 256 pixels (totaling $256 \times 256 = 65536$ pixels). In the new, larger image you only know the value of $1$ out of every $16$ pixels. How are you going to calculate the values for the rest?

[image]

Well, the methods that do that for you are called upsampling techniques. The most common are:

- [Nearest-Neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation): Copies the value from the nearest pixel.
- [Bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation): Uses all nearby pixels to calculate the pixel's value, using linear interpolations.
- [Bicubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation): Again uses all nearby pixels to calculate the pixel's values, through polynomial interpolations. Usually produces a smoother surface than the previous techniques, but its harder to compute.
- Other more complex resampling algorithms, e.g. [Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling).

An article explaining the differences among image resampling techniques can be found [here](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/thevenaz9901.pdf).

Comment: Very informative answer ! Thanks a lot.